# How to find a matrix $A$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle = x^T A y$ for the $L^2 (D)$ inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

So I know that I should have some matrix $A$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle = x^T A y$ for the $L^2 (D)$ inner product. I would like to find this $A$. My domain $D$ is a $3 \times 3$ square grid in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am assuming that the points making up this grid are $x_i = x_0 + i$ for $i = 0,1,2,3$ and $y_j = y_0 + j$ for $j = 0,1,2,3$ (note here I'm assuming the step size is 1 for both $x$ and $y$ directions).

I also am using the standard piecewise linear finite element basis functions as the basis functions for my space which I believe will come into play so $\varphi_{ij} = \phi_i(x) \phi_j(y)$ where

$\begin{equation*}
    {\large \phi _j (y) =\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
          \frac{y-y_{j-1}}{h} & y\in I_j \\
          \frac{y_{j+1}-y}{h} & y \in I_{j+1}  \\
          0 & \mbox{else}
        \end{array}
    \right.}
    \mbox{   for } j = 1,...,N-1
\end{equation*}$

I genuinely have no idea how to proceed and I've tried searching everything I can think of online but cannot find anything helpful. In general it confuses me how a vector matrix product involving functions could give us the same value as definite integration. I'm wondering if the functions involved need to be turned into values at grid points prior to computing $x^T A y$?

If you have any suggestions for resources or any comments that can help me figure this out I would be extremely grateful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Don't [delete and repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4863616/742).

Comment: I was not "angry". I pointed out that chatGPT should not be used. In response, rather than edit your post (which would have automatically bumped it, by the way), you deleted and reposted your query. That is not appropriate behavior in this site. What I want from you is that you behave appropriately. "Genuinely trying to learn" is not an excuse for violating the norms and rules of the site. Deleting and reposting is against those norms and rules. I am **informing you of this** (not "harassing you") so that you stop behaving inappropriately.

Comment: I only deleted it to change the way I was asking the question to appease your comments of strong disapproval. I was not trying to break any rules. Thanks for the input. Duly noted. Have a good day.

Comment: That's what the "Edit" button is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a bit more precise, what you have done is select a finite-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{V}_h\subset L^2(D)$ with basis elements $\varphi_k$ given by the product of your 1D basis elements as you have described. If we assume you choose a consistent way to order them, then we represent elements in $\mathcal{V}_h$ as linear combinations like so
$$u_h = \sum_{k=1}^N u_k\varphi_k,\quad v_h = \sum_{k=1}^N v_k\varphi_k.$$ Now, we certainly cannot create a finite-dimensional operator $A$ that generates the inner product on all of $L^2$, but we can create one that generates the $L^2$ inner product restricted to $\mathcal{V}_h$, since it is finie dimensional. Let $U = (u_1,\dots,u_N)$ be the vector of coefficients of the function $u_h$, then we seek a spd matrix $A$ such that
$$\langle U, AV\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^N} = \langle u_h, v_h\rangle_{L^2(D)},\quad \forall u_h,v_h\in \mathcal{V}_h,\\ \text{ where } u_h = \sum_{k=1}^N u_i \varphi_i, \, v_h = \sum_{k=1}^N v_i \varphi_i.$$

To obtain this matrix, we substitute the linear combination representation of $u_h$ and $v_h$ into the $L^2$ inner product, and manipulate until we obtain something that looks like a quadratic form in the coefficients. Ultimately, we should obtain the matrix $[A]_{ij} = \langle \varphi_i,\varphi_j\rangle_{L^2(D)}$. This matrix is $N\times N$, symmetric, and positive definite assuming that the $\varphi$'s are linearly independent. This matrix is often referred to as the *mass matrix* in finite element literature. Note that we haven't explicitly given an ordering to the $\varphi$'s, and you will have to do that yourself. However, it shouldn't affect your results as long as you are consistent in your ordering.